# iOSでアプリから確認ダイアログなしで電話をかけたい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

URLスキームを以下のように記述しています。

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "tel:0123-456-7980")!)
```

調べた結果、urlを`"tel:"`とすると確認ダイアログなし、`"telprompt:"`とすると確認ダイアログありということが（様々なHPに）書かれていたので、確認なしとしたいので前者の"tel:"で始まる文字列を使用しています。

しかしどちらを使用しても、確認ダイアログが出てしまいます。

上記の他にどこか設定変更か、コードの追加記述が必要でしょうか？
セキュリティーの観点から、確認ダイアログが出るように仕様変更されたのでしょうか？

教えていただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

XCode 8.3.2
iOS 10.3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS 10.3からtelを使っても確認ダイアログが出てきます。

セキュリティーノート

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207617

> Phone
>   Available for: iPhone 5 and later, iPad 4th generation and later, iPod touch 6th generation and later
>   Impact: A third party app can initiate a phone call without user interaction
>   Description: An issue existed in iOS allowing for calls without prompting.  This issue was addressed by prompting a user to confirm call initiation.
>   CVE-2017-2484

リリースノート

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/

> When a third party application invokes openURL: on a tel://, facetime://, or facetime-audio:// URL, iOS displays a prompt and requires user confirmation before dialing.

ダイアログなしなのはセキュリティーの問題だと判断され、直されたので、iOS10.3からはおそらくできないと思います。

Comment: やはりセキュリティーの観点からできなくなったんですね。ありがとうございました。